# how to add a razor background image

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

I am trying to add a background image to my blazor project, but when I put a background image I appear on all the pages that I have, How can I do so that the image I want in background only appears in use single page and not on the plus ones?, I have a component (which I use as layout) in which I put the following, this so that in my login I do not appear the menu (I have it as LoginLayout.razor)

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div class="col-md-10">
    @Body
</div>
```

And that LoginLayout I use on my Login.razor page

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want a background image for a specific Blazor page/component.

If you have the following setup in your site.CSS/app.CSS:

```css
.page-background-class {
    background-image:url(../images/image-name.png)
}
```

Then in your page you can enclose everything in a div element and give it the class of page-background-class:

```cs
<div class="page-background-class">
    page stuff goes here
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much man for the help, I was very thanked

Comment: Okay if you can mark the answer as the correct one by checking the tick I would be most grateful